# How to retrieve Facebook app user friends list with their details using php

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

ow i am developing social media web app i want to get app user friends list and their details i tried to retrieve user friends data using php sdk 4.0 but it gave me a empty array then i try to get data using json format. This is my code i am now trying

```
<?php
         $fb_config = array(
             'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
             'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
             'cookie' => TRUE
         );
         $this->load->library('facebook', $fb_config);
         $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

         if ($user) {
             try {
                 $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');
             } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                 $user = null;
             }
         }

         if ($user) { //ok, the user exist, proceed
             $access_token = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();

             $file = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=' . $access_token);


             $jsonFriends = json_decode($file, true);
             $Friends = $jsonFriends['data'];
         }
 ?>
```

I am getting

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in M:\xampp\htdocs\fb\demo.php on line 7

This error when i run this code.

Comment: this error is self explaining

Comment: How much do you know about PHP? Did you write this code yourself?

Comment: i am new to php development https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/get-facebook-friends-list-data-with-php-return-json-format

Comment: Well, the code in that link is just a "code fragment" from a PHP framework called CodeIgniter. It will not work on its own. If you want to develop stuff for Facebook then you should first take the time to learn PHP, and then you should take a look at [Facebook's "Getting Started" page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0).

Answer (score 0):

you need to change

```
 $this->load->library('facebook', $fb_config);
```

to

```
  FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('YOUR_APP_ID', 'YOUR_APP_SECRET');
```

as a start.

This array is usually for JavaScript SDK

```
$fb_config = array(
         'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
         'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
         'cookie' => TRUE
     );
```

And from where did you get your access token or the session.

Did you use another page with JS sdk? because I can't find an instance of "FacebookRedirectLoginHelper" or "FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper".

I really recommend that you start by going through the documentation by facebook in here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0